# JSch sftp job summary

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

```
private final String host;
    private final String userAccount;
    private final String keyDir;
    private ChannelSftp sftpChannel;
    private Session session;
    private Channel channel


public void send(List<Path> filesToSend, String destination) throws SftpException, IOException {

    if (sftpChannel == null) {
        logger.error("Failed to create SFTP channel");
    }
    for (Path file : filesToSend) {
        send(file, destination);
    }
     //summary of sent files over sftpchannel
} 

public void send(Path file, String destination) throws SftpException, IOException {

    if (sftpChannel == null) {
        logger.error("Failed to create SFTP channel");
    }
    sftpChannel.put(Files.newInputStream(file), destination + File.separator + file.getFileName());

} //end send



}//end class
```

After all the files have been sent, can somebody show me how I can get a count of how many number of files have successfully been sent. Not important but also if any failed or any kind of monitoring. How can I do this with `Jsch` library.

I would like something in my log such as :

Preparing to send [14] files

Number of files sent is [14]...

Comment: please post more code. Its not clear what you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void send(List<Path> filesToSend, String destination) {
        logger.debug("Preparing to send ["+filesToSend.size()+"] files");

        if (sftpChannel == null) {
            logger.error("Failed to create SFTP channel");
        }

        int successCount = 0;
        int failedCount = 0;

        for (Path file : filesToSend) {
            try {
              send(file, destination);
              successCount++;
            } catch (Exception e) {
              failedCount++;
            }
        }
        //summary of sent files over sftpchannel
        logger.debug("Successfully sent " + successCount);
        logger.debug("Failed to sent " + failedCount);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that jsch throws exceptions when an error occurs, why don't you just implement your own counter (just an int would work)?